# How do put two operating systems on one DVD-R?

Tags: installation, 12.10, 64-bit, 32-bit

How would I go about installing Ubuntu 32 and 64 bit 12.10 on the same disk? I would really like to do this if you could help. I'm on Ubuntu 12.10 64bit ATM if that helps.

Edit: What I meant was installing the install cd for both 32 and 64bit on the same disk not the OS itself.

On a dvd-r

Here is wqhat I'm looking for:

Ubuntu 32 and 64 bit installation disk on 1 DVD -r so when a person puts the dvd in and restarts computer they enter a menu and have to chose which OS they want to install , the 32 bit OS or the 64 bit OS of Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Do you want to have both the 32-bit and 64-bit version on your DVD?  So that it will work for any computer? A tip, use a USB instead! :)

Comment: I want to put it on a DVD -r so I can 'sell it' to someone

Comment: You can't burn a DVD with both ISOs on it, at least not in a way that is bootable. You'll need to have two different DVDs.

Comment: Is there a way to combine both .iso's  into one .iso?

Comment: Yes. You can prepare the file tree which contains everything you want and then you make one .iso. You fix all the install scripts so that the user can pick 32 or 64, and then you call this Robert Hickey's Double Ubuntu installer.

Comment: Could you put this in simpler terms. I'm new to Linux. Just getting used to it.

Answer (score 1):

The 32bit install will actually run fine on most 64bit computers, so if you want to have a single DVD that can install onto "most" computers then you should just use the 32bit version only.

Comment: The 32-bit installation will work on any setup that support 64-bit...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this isn't a possibility. However, it is possible to boot multiple operating systems from one USB drive. I use a utility called MultiSystem (instructions [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/)) which lets you drag and drop ISOs onto a USB and creates a GRUB bootloader on the USB to choose which system you actually want to boot.